# How do I change the color of the drawable in a button?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a button in the list of items rendered with recycler view with a drawable icon. Here is my code.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button_like"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black_24dp"
  android:text="@string/label_like"
  android:textSize="11dp"
  style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Now I want to change the color of the icon `ic_thumb_up_black_24dp` which is anydpi xml icon from Android material design icons.

I tried `android:drawableTint="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"` but it does not work.

`android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"` works only on the text color but not on the icon. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: use `Drawable#setTint(int tintColor)` on your left compound drawable

Comment: Thank you @pskink for the hint. Is there anyway I can do it in xml?

Comment: you could try `android:tint` inside xml bitmap resource